# How can I make this part of code shorten?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I only know that this part of code is not good for performance web application because it spent a lot of time during execution two SQL query instead of one. I want to read your suggestions about this part of code. Also, I want to read your code solution of this. The code is working ok.

I appreciate your help.

Thank you in advance

```
<html>
<body>
    <select name="category">
        <option value="category">category name</option>
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT category.name as cat, article.name as art from category
        JOIN article ON category.id = article.id";
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        echo "
        <option value='".$row["cat"]."'>".$row["cat"]."</option>";
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
        ?>
    </select>
    <select name="article">
        <option value="articlename">article name</option>
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT category.name as cat, article.name as art from category
        JOIN article ON category.id = article.id";
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        echo "
        <option value='".$row["art"]."'>".$row["art"]."</option>";
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
        ?>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A well indented code is more pleasant to read

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is largely an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to make 2 connections to the db for getting the same data. You could create a collection of objects and use them in place like such...

```
<?php
  $arr = [];

  $sql = "SELECT category.name as cat, article.name as art from category 
  JOIN article ON category.id = article.id";

  $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
      $obj = (object) [
          "cat" => $row["cat"],
          "art" => $row["art"]
      ];

      array_push($arr, $obj);
  }

  mysqli_close($conn);
?>

<select name="category">
<option value="category">category name</option>
foreach($arr as $obj) {
    ?>
        <option value='"<?php echo $obj->cat; ?>"'><?php echo $obj->cat; ?></option>
    <?php
}
```

```
<select name="article">
<option value="articlename">article name</option>
foreach($arr as $obj) {
    ?>
        <option value='"<?php echo $obj->art; ?>"'><?php echo $obj->art; ?></option>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare the strings that will hold the `<option>` in 1 loop, then simply echo them.

In example :

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT category.name as cat,
               article.name as art
        FROM category 
        JOIN article
        ON category.id = article.id";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$articles = "";
$categories = "";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $categories .= "<option value='" . $row["cat"] . "'>" . $row["cat"] . "</option>";
    $articles .= "<option value='" . $row["art"] . "'>" . $row["art"] . "</option>";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
<select name="category">
    <option value="category">category name</option>
    <?php echo $categories; ?>
</select>
<select name="article">
    <option value="articlename">article name</option>
    <?php echo $articles; ?>
</select>
```